# Why does my Oracle DataSource have a replay error only when unit testing?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbc

My Spring Boot 1.5.17 (Spring 4.3.20) server works fine with bootRun or when deployed.

However, I have an Oracle DataSource that fails **only when unit-testing**:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Server is sending a non-null replay context
>   but our replayModes=[]

A Google Search for this error doesn't have exact results.

I am able to unit-test with a different Oracle database.

I get the error with a full Application testing context

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = { TestingUserConfiguration.class, Application.class }
)
```

As well as just the single DataSource config and Service

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
        MyDbConfig.class,
        MyService.class
})
```

Both `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource` and `oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleConnectionPoolDataSourceImpl` have the error.
UCP makes no difference.

`OracleConnectionPoolDataSourceImpl` has a different error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature

Tried upgrading from OJDBC 12.2 to 2018.3, no difference.

Has anyone seen this error before?
Any ideas on why it only appears with Spring unit tests?

Comment: Me as well I am suffering this: https://community.oracle.com/message/15117270#15117270

Answer (score 5):

After much head scratching, I found that doing this in the test suite:

```
static {
 ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().setPackageAssertionStatus("oracle.jdbc.driver", false);  
}
```

Solved My issue, I am sure this is a bug in the oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun class

Answer (score 1):

You can add "-da:oracle..." to your JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to turn off oracle asserts.   To get around this.

Trent

Comment: thank you! It solved my issue that had been poisoning my life for last two days :)