# java.lang.AssertionError: Server is sending a non-null replay context but our replayModes=[]

Tags: java, sql, oracle, junit

When I try to connect to the oracle database from a separate main class,

```
 try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/service", "username", "pwd");
```

I am able to connect but when I use the same connection inside a test ng or junit test, am getting the following error :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Server is sending a non-null replay context but our replayModes=[]
```

Could someone please help me to understand what is happening !

Just tried the answers from this link and it dint work for me :
[Why does my Oracle DataSource have a replay error only when unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383705/why-does-my-oracle-datasource-have-a-replay-error-only-when-unit-testing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my Oracle DataSource have a replay error only when unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383705/why-does-my-oracle-datasource-have-a-replay-error-only-when-unit-testing)

Comment: That is a little bit different and the answers there did not work . Thanks Karthi

Comment: In that case please mention in the question that you have tried the solution an it didn't work also what is the difference between you question and the linked one, because now your question is same as the linked duplicate most likely it will be flagged duplicate by some one else.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add

```
static {
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().setPackageAssertionStatus("oracle.jdbc.driver", false);
}
```